# Having bug in taking input in some format and storing it in desired format in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm not able to get input in my desired format. I'm provided with the following sample input format -

```
3 4
1 1 1 2
3 1 1 1
1 1 1 2
2 2 2 1
1 1 2 2
1 1 2 2
```

The first line contains `m` and `n` values, `m` is the number of rows and `n` is the number of columns. **Each cell contains a list of 2 numbers.**
Therefore, the next `2m` lines contains `n` integers on each line. The first `m` lines contain **1st number** of each cell. The second `m` lines contains **2nd number** of each cell.

For the given sample input, the cells get values like -

```
[1,2] [1,2] [1,2] [2,1]
[3,1] [1,1] [1,2] [1,2]
[1,1] [1,1] [1,2] [2,2]
```

This is the desired format I want to store data in my `matrix` list variable.

**Below is my code for storing data in this format.**

```
matrix = [[[0]*2]*n]*m
for i in range(0, 2):
    for j in range(0, m):
        temp = list(map(int, input().split()))
        for k in range(0, n):
            matrix[j][k][i] = temp[k]
```

This should work correctly but its not. I can't find the problem. I'm getting my `matrix` variable filled with `2` only. In each and every cell `2` is stored.

Now my `matrix` variable storing this data -

```
[[[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]],
 [[2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2], [2, 2]]]
```

*The correct values should be -*

```
[[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [2, 1]],
 [[3, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2]],
 [[1, 1], [1, 1], [1, 2], [2, 2]]]
```

**I want to know where is the problem in my code first before any alternate solutions.**

Comment: What do you mean by "input"? Is this the content of some ascii file? Do you want to import it? Or should that really be input manually number by number by a user in your nested loop...?

Comment: @SpghttCd "input" means the user will manually enter input in the console line by line.

Comment: Unerstood. Then you should catch the exception thrown in the case that the input doesn't fit to the data you epect, i.e. a string without spaces in between and/or not int-castable characters in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Disclaimer: This is Untested

The way you're making your matrix is going to be making references to the same list so when you edit one, its going to be editing the others too

```
matrix = [[[0]*2]*n]*m
```

should be

```
matrix = [[[0, 0] for _ in range(n)] for _ in range(m)]
```

Answer (score 1):

The mistake is only in your matrix declaration. If you go by that, every time a pair is updated it gets copied n times and then, compied m times again.

If you want to correct it, you can try:

```
matrix = [[[0, 0] for x in range(n)] for y in range(m)]
```

Comment: Sorry, a comma got lost in there, fixed it.

Comment: Thanks, it helped. But I've to accept the other answer because it was posted earlier.